# Why does reduce operator does not work the way I expect it to?

Tags: fold, reduction, apl, dyalog

I am trying to solve [Euler 18](https://projecteuler.net/problem=18) in Dyalog APL, and I am not able to understand why my solution does not work.

The problem is as follow:

> By starting at the top of the triangle below and moving to adjacent
> numbers on the row below, the maximum total from top to bottom is 23.

```
   3 
  7 4 
 2 4 6
8 5 9 3
```

> That is, 3 + 7 + 4 + 9 = 23.

Taking the example that I represent this way:

```
d ← (3 0 0 0)  (7 4 0 0)  (2 4 6 0)  (8 5 9 3)
```

I am trying to solve it this way:

```
{⍵+((2⌈/⍺)),0}/⌽d
```

Which gives me this array: 22 19 15 0, where the bigger number is 22, which is not the right answer for the problem, which would be 23.

I am getting this behavior (left to right for ease of reading):

```
(2⌈/(8 5 9 3),0)+(2⌈/(2 4 6 0),0)+(2⌈/(7 4 0 0),0)+(2⌈/(3 0 0 0),0)
```

Which gives me the same result as the function.

What I would expect is this behavior (where each statement is substituted directly in the next line):

```
    (2⌈/(8 5 9 3)),0
(2 4 6 0)+8 9 9 0
    (2⌈/(10 13 15 0)),0
(7 4 0 0)+13 15 15 0
    (2⌈/(20 19 15 0)),0
(3 0 0 0) + 20 19 15 0
23 19 15 0
```

Am I wondering where I am misunderstanding something in the APL process that leads to a different result than the one I am expecting.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the description of Problem 18 to the question? Even a single sentence such as "I need to find the sum of the maximum element selected from each subarray" would be helpful, as the link doesn't lead to problem 18 directly.

Comment: That is a good point, I did add the description, but I can't seem to fix the issue with the link, it showed me the archive page the first time I clicked on it and afterwards it is alright.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/` works in the reverse way to what you expected - it evaluates through the array right-to-left.

`F/a b c d` is `⊂a F b F c F d`, or, with parentheses, `⊂(a F (b F (c F d)))`.

After removing the `⌽` and swapping `⍺` and `⍵`, you get `{⍺+(2⌈/⍵),0}/d`, which gives the result you want.

Comment: The OP also doesn't need to append a zero at each step and pad each row ([TIO](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBCkKj9omKGjoGGsqaJgrmGgqKGgYKZgomIEYFgqmCpYKxppcXNWPendpGz3q6dB/1Lu1Vj8FAA))